# How can I force pytz to use currently standard timezones?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

Consider the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pytz


new_years_in_new_york = datetime(
    year=2020,
    month=1, 
    day=1,
    hour=0,
    minute=0,
    tzinfo = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

I now I have a datetime object representing January 1, midnight, in New York. Oddly, if I use pytz to convert this to UTC, I'll get an odd datetime off by several minutes:

```py
new_years_in_new_york.astimezone(pytz.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 4, 56, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Notice that midnight in New York, in pytz, is **4:56** in UTC. Elsewhere on Stack Overflow, I learned that's because [pytz uses your `/usr/share/zoneinfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35779449/170431) data, which uses *local mean time* to account for timezones before standardization. This can be shown here:

```py
pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
# <DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>
```

See that `LMK-1 day, 19:04:00 STD`? That's a local mean time offset, not the offset I want, which is US/Eastern *not* during daylight savings time.

Is there a way I can force pytz to use what is currently the standard set of offsets based on a current date? On New Years 2020, it should just be UTC-5. If the date I supplied were during daylight savings time, I would want UTC-4. I'm confused as to why pytz would use a LMT-based offset for a 2020 date.

Comment: This shot in the foot is exactly why you should not use pytz anymore. Use the standard library zoneinfo instead.

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn but does `zoneinfo` make the same problem in reverse?  If I try to get the offset for a date in 1850 for example, does it deliver today's offset?  I think `pytz`'s `localize` gets it right.

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn please ignore my question, I found a version of Python 3.9 online and had a play with `zoneinfo`.  It does indeed adjust the `utcoffset` for the date it's applied to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> new_years_in_new_york
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)
```

Notice the odd offset in that datetime. You're not creating this datetime correctly.

> This library only supports two ways of building a localized time. The
> first is to use the `localize()` method provided by the pytz library.
> This is used to localize a naive datetime (`datetime` with no timezone
> information):
>
> ```
> >>> loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
> >>> print(loc_dt.strftime(fmt))
> 2002-10-27 06:00:00 EST-0500
> ```
>
> The second way of building a localized time is by converting an
> existing localized time using the standard `astimezone()` method:
>
> ```
> >>> ams_dt = loc_dt.astimezone(amsterdam)
> >>> ams_dt.strftime(fmt)
> '2002-10-27 12:00:00 CET+0100'
> ```
>
> Unfortunately using the `tzinfo` argument of the standard `datetime`
> constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.
>
> ```
> >>> datetime(2002, 10, 27, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=amsterdam).strftime(fmt)
> '2002-10-27 12:00:00 LMT+0020'
> ```
>
> http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic