# Python3.7 datetime.timestamp() returns a wrong value by two minutes (???)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp, pytz

If I have this code:

```
import datetime
import pytz

dt = datetime.datetime(
    year=2021,
    month=3,
    day=3,
    hour=11,
    minute=30,
    second=15,
    microsecond=0,
    tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Prague")
)
```

Then this is the result of `dt.timestamp()`:

```
1614767535.0
```

Which translates to **Wed Mar 03 2021 10:32:15 GMT+0000** while I would expect **10:30:15** instead.

What's the deal here?

Comment: some more background info : https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Prague")`

Explanation is here: [Python pytz timezone function returns a timezone that is off by 9 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462876/python-pytz-timezone-function-returns-a-timezone-that-is-off-by-9-minutes)